# Как узнать текст не в зависимости от его трансформации

Tags: python

У меня есть код.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если пользователь вводил да/нет то оно делало его прописанный сценарий.
Только как сделать так, чтобы не проверять написано-ли дА либо Да или ДА, а сразу понимать что написал пользователь.
Спасибо

Comment: почитайте:                    https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html         S.lower() Преобразование строки к нижнему регистру.  все Да,дА и ДА станут да

Comment: Да / Нет? Супер, конечно, но как насчет msvcrt? В частности ф-я getch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы привести строку в нижний регистр, воспользуйтесь методом [lower()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm):

```py
answer = 'ДыА'
lower_answer = answer.lower()
print(lower_answer) #=> дыа
```